# Google Script web app Returning as blank after submission

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a simple Google Script form that will submit data to my google sheets.
But after submission the form goes to blank page. I just copy the codes on a tutorials and follow the instructions to the T. But I'm still getting the blank page.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                        <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">Case Tracking</p>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                <label for="cseid">Case ID</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cseid" name="cseid" placeholder="Caseid">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="Origowner">Original Owner</label>
                              <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="Origowner" name="Origowner">
                                <option selected>Original Owner</option>
                                <option>Ben</option>
                                <option>Tom</option>
                                <option>Cat</option>
                                <option>Dog</option>
                                <option>Food</option>
                                <option>Card</option>
                                <option>Box</option>
                                <option>Chess</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="Closingowner">Closing Owner</label>
                              <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="Closingowner" name="Closingowner">
                                <option selected>Closing Owner</option>
                                <option>Ben</option>
                                <option>Tom</option>
                                <option>Cat</option>
                                <option>Dog</option>
                                <option>Food</option>
                                <option>Card</option>
                                <option>Box</option>
                                <option>Chess</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="Emailtype">Email Type</label>
                              <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="Emailtype" name="Emailtype">
                                <option selected>Email Type</option>
                                <option>Pink</option>
                                <option>Blue</option>
                                <option>red</option>
                                <option>Black</option>
                              </select>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label for="Emailstate">Email State</label>
                              <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="Emailstate" name="Emailstate">
                                <option selected>Email State</option>
                                <option>Purple</option>
                                <option>Yellow</option>
                                <option>Green</option>
                                <option>Magenta</option>
                              </select> 
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>        
  </body>
</html>
```

Code GS

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate ();
  
}

function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

function processForm(formObject){
  var url="urlfile"
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws=ss.getSheetByName("Data");

  ws.appendRow([
    formObject.cseid,
    formObject.Origowner,
    formObject.Closingowner,
    formObject.Emailtype,
    formObject.Emailstate

  ]);
}
```

JavaScript

```
<script>

  function preventFormSubmit(){
    var forms=document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i=0;i<forms.lenght;i++){
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
window.addEventListener('load',preventFormSubmit);

function handleFormSubmit(formObject){
  google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

</script>
```

I've tried finding answers here, But I do not have any knowledge about this as I just trying to learn through tutorials

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `lenght` of `for (var i=0;i<forms.lenght;i++){` should be `length`.
- And, in your `handleFormSubmit`, before `google.script.run.processForm(formObject)` is finished, `document.getElementById("myForm").reset()` is run. By this, the value might not be able to be put into the Spreadsheet because `google.script.run` is run with the asynchronous process.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your `JavaScript` is modified.

```html
<script>
function preventFormSubmit() {
  var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
  for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
    forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  }
}
window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(_ => {
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
  }).processForm(formObject);
}
</script>
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)